# App.post doesn't send data to the database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm following a tutorial and I'm at the point where I'm trying to send a data to my MySQL database using the `app.post`. When I go to the localhost site running the request (my localhost is `localhost:8800/shoes`) it doesn't update/insert the data, it only shows the current database I have in MySQL. But in the video as the JS file was saved, the data got uploaded immediately.

```js
import express from "express"
import mysql from "mysql"

const app = express()
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "qwerty",
    database: "marketplace"
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("this is the backend")
})

app.get("/shoes", (req, res) => {
    const q = "SELECT * FROM `marketplace`.`shoes`"
    db.query(q, (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err)

        return res.json(data)
    })
})
 
app.post("/shoes", (req, res) => {
    const q = "INSERT INTO `marketplace`.`shoes` (`id`, `prod_name`, `prod_description`, `image`) VALUES(?)";
    const values = [
        "222",
        "item3",
        "item 3 description",
        "item3 image"
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err)
        return res.json(data)
    })
})

app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log("connected to backend")
})
```

I tried to troubleshoot it by removing the `app.get` and I receive in my localhost is `Cannot GET /shoes`.

```js
import express from "express"
import mysql from "mysql"

const app = express()
const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "qwerty",
    database: "marketplace"
})

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.json("this is the backend")
})

// app.get("/shoes", (req, res) => {
//     const q = "SELECT * FROM `marketplace`.`shoes`"
//     db.query(q, (err, data) => {
//         if(err) return res.json(err)

//         return res.json(data)
//     })
// })
 
app.post("/shoes", (req, res) => {
    const q = "INSERT INTO `marketplace`.`shoes` (`id`, `prod_name`, `prod_description`, `image`) VALUES(?)";
    const values = [
        "222",
        "item3",
        "item 3 description",
        "item3 image"
    ];

    db.query(q, [values], (err, data) => {
        if(err) return res.json(err)
        return res.json(data)
        //return res.json("test")
    })
})

app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log("connected to backend")
})
```

So I suspect the issue is in the `app.post` but I have the same exact code in the video. I even tried the async and it still doesn't work

```js
app.post("/shoes", async (req, res)
```

Please help what to do

Comment: Shouldn't your sql query `VALUES` have a `?` for each argument, so, `VALUES(?,?,?,?)` ?

Comment: The tutorial I'm following is using `VALUES(?)`. It worked on there. Though I tried `VALUES(?,?,?,?)` but it still doesn't work

Comment: @chrisbyte is right, if you just want to use one `?` don't wrap it in parentheses.  `INSERT INTO shoes ('id', 'prod_name', 'prod_description', 'image') VALUES ?`

Comment: @Shivam I tried your suggestion, it still doesnt insert the data.

Answer (score 0):

From this part of your description

> I tried to troubleshoot it by removing the app.get and I receive in my localhost is Cannot GET /shoes.

It sounds like when you're trying to add data to the shoes table and thus invoke the `app.post()` method you're actually still calling the get method.

Look at the frontend code that is attempting to save the data and make sure you have something like `method: post` in the options. Or if you're using a tool like Postman to test the API, make sure postman is configured with the post method.

Comment: I currently dont have a frontend or button of some sort. Its only being processed by the time I saved the JS file (I'm using nodemon). I already tried using the postman but I get Cloud Agent Error: Can not send requests to localhost.

Comment: What are you doing to trigger the app.post() code? Using a web browser to open localhost:8800/shoes? If so, then it's only going to be a get request. You'd have to put together at least a tiny HTML page with a short script to trigger fetch with the post method.

Comment: I tried to do what you were suggesting but it still doesnt give me the data